# Tomcat shows different number formatting for GWT

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gwt, number-formatting

I have following code to format float numbers

```
NumberFormat nmf = NumberFormat.getFormat("#.00");
totalAmount=Float.parseFloat(nmf.format(totalAmount));
```

When I run my application in eclipse for value `69.965` it gives `69.96` while when I deploy it on tomcat server (locally) it gives me `69.97` as result!

What's the reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say: _"When I run my application in eclipse"_? Dev mode?

Comment: Yes, I run in eclipse in dev mode

Comment: Can you add line nmf.getRoundingMode() and see what it returns?

Comment: Solved! I used :                                                           new BigDecimal(totalAmount).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)